# How to start server by my source code (app.js) using FTP?

Tags: node.js, ftp, server, filezilla

I'm new to develop server. I already coded my server app.js with Node js and I tested it locally and successfully.

The way I tested my server is that after executing the terminal, moving to the directory having app.js file, command app.js. So then my server is alive and I could test what I want to.

But it's my first time to use FTP to make my server globally. By FTP, I don't know how to do 'node app.js' command.

And if it's done, I don't know the path to test my GET, POST methods.

Comment: FTP is a protocol for File Transfer. You cannot execute remote commands with it. You need a hosting service that provides other types of access (e.g. SSH) or a control panel to launch Node apps.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you, it sounds like I can do it by terminal... Isn't it? Can you explain some more how to command remotely?

Comment: Well... Type `node app.js` and hit *enter* to begin with... Do you have SSH access? Does your service include Node?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Oh I accessed my remote server by terminal successfully, thank you! But I can not install node js...

Comment: You are normally not allowed to install software in hosted servers, unless you pay for a dedicated server (physical or virtual). But you can find shared hosting with Node support if you need it.